# Could not load file or assembly Newtonsoft.json. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have an c# app. When i am running this app normal way from visual studio or using double click to the .exe file everything is file and working correct. But i have to execute the .exe file file from sql server. I am using xp_cmdshell and i have this error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not  load
>   file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0,  Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one  of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

My app code is this

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AndroidParse
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //SqlDataReader reader;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

            string queryString = "select device_id from Requests where ID_Requests = 'xxx'";
            string connectionString = "Data Source=xxx\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
            "Initial Catalog=xxx;" +
            "User id=xxx;" +
            "Password=xxx;";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                try
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);

                        bool isPushMessageSend = false;

                        string postString = "";
                        string urlpath = "https://api.parse.com/1/push";
                        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlpath);

                        postString = "{\"data\": { \"alert\": \"Finally is working\" },\"where\": { \"device_id\": \"" + reader[0] + "\" }}";
                        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = postString.Length;
                        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id", "xxx");
                        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Parse-REST-API-KEY", "xxx");
                        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

                        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
                        requestWriter.Write(postString);
                        requestWriter.Close();
                        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();


                        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                            JObject jObjRes = JObject.Parse(responseText);
                            if (Convert.ToString(jObjRes).IndexOf("true") != -1)
                            {
                                isPushMessageSend = true;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }


        }

        private static void println()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it sounds like you haven't copied `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` alongside your app...

Comment: Try changing the Copy Local property of the .dll to True.

Answer (score 1):

You need the Newtonsoft.json.dll available on the server

**Simple:** Keep all the files from the bin-folder along with the executable, make sure the reference property "Copy Local" is set to true for Newtonsoft.Json

**Advanced:** Alternatively, add the Newtonsoft.Json.dll to the Global Assembly Cache (GAC)

Don't know how to add a dll to the GAC? [Check this article out](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22618.how-to-install-a-dll-to-the-gac-on-windows-server-2012-using-only-powershell.aspx) to learn how to do it using Powershell

Comment: Thank you vey much. I try the simple way and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

First try to reinstall library using.. Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Hello here is all the steps that worked for me :

First uninstall / reinstall Package
[Open Package Manager Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xufnN.png)

```
Uninstall-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Force
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Get the DDl Folder

[Package object Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z5E7.png)

Get the Path :

[PAth DDL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmldY.png)

Register the DLL by Opening Power Shell as admin and run this with your Path

```
Set-location "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Newtonsoft.Json\v4.0_13.0.0.0__30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"            
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")            
$publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish            
$publish.GacInstall("C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Newtonsoft.Json\v4.0_13.0.0.0__30ad4fe6b2a6aeed\Newtonsoft.Json.dll")
```

Worked for me

thanks